# How to apply UDF to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create a function that will cleanup and dataframe that I put through the function. But I noticed that the df returned is cleanued up but not in place of the original df.

How can I run a UDF on a dataframe and keep the updated dataframe saved in place?

p.s. I know I can combine these rules into one line but the function I am creating is a lot more complex so I don't want to combine for this example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Key': ['3', '9', '9', '9', '9','34','34', '34'], 
              'LastFour': ['2290', '0087', 'M433','M433','25','25','25','25'],
              'NUM': [20120528, 20120507, 20120615,20120629,20120621,20120305,20120506,20120506]})

def cleaner(x):
    x = x[x['Key'] == '9']
    x = x[x['LastFour'] == 'M433']
    x = x[x['NUM'] == 20120615]
    return x

cleaner(df)
```

Result from the UDF:

```
    Key LastFour    NUM
2   9   M433        20120615
```

But if I run the df after the function then I still get the original dataset:

```
    Key LastFour   NUM
0   3   2290       20120528
1   9   0087       20120507
2   9   M433       20120615
3   9   M433       20120629
4   9   25         20120621
5   34  25         20120305
6   34  25         20120506
7   34  25         20120506
```

Comment: You don't need an ugly function. You can use `df.query`, it's tons faster: `df = df.query("Key == '9' and LastFour == 'M433' and NUM == 20120615") `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the result of `cleaner(df)` back to `df` as so:

```
df = cleaner(df)
```

An alternative method is to use [`pd.DataFrame.pipe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) to pass your dataframe through a function:

```
df = df.pipe(cleaner)
```

Comment: Wow. SO simple. Thank you! Is one approach better than the other for this?

Comment: The two approaches are comparable, there should be no significant efficiency discrepancy. There is a train of thought that `pandas` [method chaining](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/method-chaining.html) via tools such as `df.pipe` is the way forward. I'm not yet convinced in the general case, but in certain situations it can be more readable.